# Как получить номер выбранного элемента listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

Как можно получить номер выбранного элемента из `tkinter.Listbox()`?

```
from tkinter import *

class ListBox:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainwindow = Tk()
        self.listResult()
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()

    def listGet(self,event):
        widgetEvent = event.widget
        appSelected = widgetEvent.curselection()

        if ( len(appSelected) == 1 ):
            selected = widgetEvent.get(appSelected[0])
            print(selected)

    def listResult(self):
        self.appsListBox = Listbox(self.mainwindow)
        self.appsListBox.insert(END, *("App 1","App 2","App 3"))

        for i in range(0, self.appsListBox.size()):
            if ( self.appsListBox.get(i)[0] == "-" ):
                self.appsListBox.itemconfig(i,
                foreground="gray", \
                selectforeground="white", \
                selectbackground=self.appsListBox.itemcget(i,"background"))

    self.appsListBox.pack()
    self.appsListBox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",self.listGet)

ListBox()
```

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно? У вас метод listGet выводит на консоль номер выбранного элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, эти строки:

```
self.appsListBox.pack()
self.appsListBox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",self.listGet)
```

должны быть внутри метода внутри метода `listResult()`, а не на уровне определения класса:

```
def listResult(self):
    self.appsListBox = Listbox(self.mainwindow)
    self.appsListBox.insert(END, *("App 1","App 2","App 3"))

    for i in range(0, self.appsListBox.size()):
        if self.appsListBox.get(i)[0] == "-":
            self.appsListBox.itemconfig(i,
                foreground="gray",
                selectforeground="white",
                selectbackground=self.appsListBox.itemcget(i,"background"))

    self.appsListBox.pack()
    self.appsListBox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",self.listGet)
```

По поводу получения номера выбранного элемента, можно добавить в класс `ListBox` метод примерно следующего вида:

```
def get_selection(self):
    list_box = self.appsListBox
    selection = list_box.curselection()
    if len(selection) == 1:
        return selection[0]
    else:
        return None
```

Метод будет возвращать либо `None`, если ничего не выбрано, либо номер выбранного элемента.

Другой вариант - добавить нужное действие в метод `listGet` там где сейчас находится `print`. Номер выбранного элемента та тот момент будет храниться в `appSelected[0]`.